# Google Captcha - How to pass with Selenium or HtmlUnit

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

I wonder if anyone has ever managed to simulate the validation of Google Captcha (the one that is asked to do some selection of images according to the response).

Has anyone had this problem?
I would like through the coordinates that the framework could simulate the click of the array of images according to the values ​​reported. Example, image {0; 3; 7}

Comment: You mean you want to break the captcha?

Comment: Good luck... Hope you will.

Comment: To learn why it is so hard watch these two videos https://youtu.be/jCr6rNaZ9EU and https://youtu.be/fsF7enQY8uI